# Bind gridview using entity framework navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, navigation-properties

Suppose I have two tables, category and product. category has navigation property as product and product has navigation. Now I want to show categories in gridview along top 3 with products inside them.

```
____________________________________________________________
Category Name|  Description | Product Name | Unit Price
------------------------------------------------------------
Cat1         | Cat1         |  Prod1 Cat1  |  100
                            |  Prod2 Cat1  |   50
                            |  Prod3 Cat1  |   50
-------------------------------------------------------------
Cat2         | Cat2         |  Prod1 Cat2  |  100
                            |  Prod2 Cat2  |   50
                            |  Prod3 Cat2  |   50
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

My mark-up so far

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCat" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="CategoryName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Products">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="grdProd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product" DataField="ProductName" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="UnitPrice" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And code behind

```
grdCat.DataSource = entities.Categories.Include("Products").ToList();
            grdCat.DataBind();
```

I have got no clue how to get it done. `OnRowBound` event is fine but getting suspension that navigation property could help.

Comment: did u get an answer how to do this after same type of thing

Comment: @kymberly yup. I did. I will post answer soon, thanks for reminding

Comment: its cause i need be able to show description instead of a code in a foreign key value

Comment: It can be done. I am in office and I did that task at home. That's why can't post answer now, can you show me your code?